# How do I get back my answer for a deleted question to save it for future reference?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions

[What are the best practices for testing "different layers" in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543117/what-are-the-best-practices-for-testing-different-layers-in-django) is a question that was deleted on Stack Overflow.

I put a lot of effort answering that question, and I would like to get back my answer to save it for future reference. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd vote to undelete it but its locked and was deleted by a moderator.... too bad SE feels the need to delete useful content just because it doesn't fit their ideal question standards

Comment: @Rachel One could say it's too bad that you don't understand what the question standards are.  Just saying, it goes both ways.

Comment: @casperOne I understand SE question standards now (I didn't always), but I don't agree with them :) If a question is clear, on-topic, useful, and helps many people, I think the question is valid. Thanks for undeleting it though.

Comment: @Rachel I accept that you don't agree with them, but frankly, aren't we at the point where *everyone* knows that you don't agree with them?  Your comments to that point are ubiquitous and are *noise* at this point.  You could have said "I'd vote to undelete it but its locked and was deleted by a moderator...." and left it at that, and that would have been *much* more constructive than the rest of your comment.  I'm urging you to be more constructive rather than sniping .  It benefits no one.

Comment: @Rachel No, it really isn't.  And so what?  The questions get undeleted, which is what you wanted.  So again, you're commenting about something, making noise (because your comments are *not* contributing to getting the content undeleted) and not really contributing anything constructive.  Again, I'm asking you to stop with the sniping and be a *constructive* contributor on meta, even in your comments.  I've already shown an example of how you can do that.

Comment: @casperOne I'm sorry you see it that way. I deleted my previous comment right after I posted it because I didn't want to get into a comment war with you. My understanding of MSO is that its for "bugs, features, and *discussion* of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Q&A engine". I didn't realize voicing a related opinion on SE policies to a MSO question was considered not constructive, and am sorry if it offended you or others.

Comment: @Rachel Your comments as worded are not for the purposes of discussion.  They are for the purpose of beating a dead horse.  It offends only so much in that it's noise and doesn't actively add anything of value because you do it so often.  We end up tuning you out as a result and then it just annoys everyone.  If you don't agree with something, find constructive ways to challenge the status quo (it *can* be done) without taking pot shots in the comments.

Comment: @casper - I don't want to start a new answer for this, but locking seems inappropriate to me here.  OP has been warned about bumping.  It seems to me the recourse is to drop the mod hammer of Thor on him if he does it again, not lock the whole thread.

Comment: @AdamRackis I'll leave it locked for a week.  Then we'll see what happens after that.  If we have to revisit it, then we'll have to look at permanently locking or taking more action against the OP.

Answer (score 10):

I've copied the source and [put it in a private pastie for you](http://pastie.org/private/cryveol2mvkfsplsiypjhq).

Any user with [10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) or more can still view and edit deleted posts.

Comment: great, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

I appreciate the effort that you put into that post.  However, the post is a subjective question, and not suitable for the site, hence it's closing as Not Constructive.  This question should have never seen the light of day in the first place.

In the future, I'd recommend that you vote to close the question as not constructive and possibly flag questions like this for moderator attention to be closed as such if the velocity of close votes isn't enough to get the question closed.  This is to save you from spending the energy on an answer that very well might not exist in the future (if it's not constructive and closed at such, it might be deleted).

The deletion and lock (not historical) are not your fault, but the fault of the asker.  The asker made a number of insignificant edits (over 20 in fact) in order to bump the question here on Stack Overflow.  We don't do "bumps" of that nature here.  Hence the lock.

I've undeleted the question, but left the lock on it (and made it community wiki, rep should not have been gained because of abuses of the edit system).  Unfortunately, the poster can't be relied upon to *not* try and bump the question again.  Note also that in the future, someone might delete the question, because it's inherently not constructive.

Comment: I agree with you, I saw what the asker was doing and in fact I thought it was more suited for a programmers question, besides that I did put a lot of effort in the answering so I just wanted my answer back. thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Hassek No problem.